# twitter bootstrap collapse want to show last two li

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for responsive design.
i have comment module like in facebook.
have shown all comment in `<li></li>`
i have collapsed `ul` using `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comm"`
i want to show last two li default.. .it collapse all li.
now how to make visible last two li
my code

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comm"> Comments</a>  
 <ul id="comm" class="comentbox collapse">
<li>
this is first comment   
</li>
<li>
this is 2 comment   
</li>
<li>
this is first comment   
</li>
<li>
this is 3 comment   
</li>
<li>
this is 4 comment   
</li>
</ul>
```

i need to show last two li default.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class `in` to your `ul` to let it show all the `li` by default:

```
<ul id="comm" class="comentbox collapse in">
```

Then you can use jQuery to hide the first 3 `li` and toggle it when click on the hyperlink:

```
$('#comm li').slice(0,3).hide();

var click = 0;
$("a").click(function() {
    click++;
    if (click == 2) {
        $('#comm li').slice(0,3).show();
    }           
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3349/)**</kbd>

Comment: but the no of li is not fixed. .

Comment: then you can calculate the total lenth of your `li` and pass inside `slice` function.